# How to create my own form in joomla

Tags: joomla

I want to create my own form that are submitted and values of that form will be stored in joomla database. How can i used the Joomla connection code to interacte with the joomla database.

Answer (score 16):

If you just want to get your work done, there are some components already avaiable in [Joomla Extension's website](http://extensions.joomla.org/) to your form's needs. [CkForms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/4939) is a good one, you can create simple forms with it that are automatically saved in the database (supports upload of files too).

If you want to learn how to write extensions in Joomla, you should read [Joomla Official Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) website.

Extensions in Joomla are divided in "Components", "Modules" and "Plugins". More informations about these differences can be found [here](http://www.ultijoomla.com/blog/Joomla-Components-Modules-and-Plugins.html) and [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=471&t=228435).

What you're trying to achieve sounds a "component" to me. Downloading the CkForms and reading it's source code should get you started to Joomla's way of writing components.

EDIT: Joomla has a huge API with a lot of features. It has a [database module](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Database/JDatabase.html) of it's own, with insert methods and such. Reading Joomla's API website before implementing your component it's a good idea to avoid "reinventing the wheel" and it's a good practice since those methods are extensively tested by all Joomla users.

Comment: These Links are not active now - http://www.ultijoomla.com/blog/Joomla-Components-Modules-and-Plugins.html  http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Database/JDatabase.html

Comment: Here you can find information about difference between "Component", "Modules" and "Plugins" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478220/difference-between-components-modules-extensions-and-plugins-in-joomla

Answer (score 7):

The JForm class helps you build forms.

Documentation can be found here:

- joomla CMS: http://docs.joomla.org/API16:JForm
- joomla API: http://api.joomla.org/11.4/Joomla-Platform/Form/JForm.html

This class provides you with ready to use form elements and form loading and/or processing methods

This class includes validation methods, date picker control, color picker, etc.

Of course, as another mentioned above, if you are building a module, component, or application, you will need to learn how to to develop a module, component or application. Of these three, the module is the easiest to implement.

The application gives you much freedom b/c you are not constrained to the CMS paradigm, front and back end complexities. However, there is little documentation about how to develop applications with Joomla framework b/c joomla as a framework is relatively new

This tutorial gets you started understanding how to use JForm to create a form in Joomla: http://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/getting-started-with-jform/

Comment: both of the documentation links seems to be dead.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could just create add a html module to any position and then write the form in html i.e.

```
<form method="post" action="mycreatedpage.php"> <input  type="text"/> <input type="submit">
```

Now just create a page that handles the code by emailing or inserting into db. I havent tried it but i think it should work.

Comment: how to create the mycreatedpage.php ? I mean where to put it ? Not in an article right ?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like everyone already told you almost everything I know except for the [component creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/). Very easy to use, and it follows Joomla standards. Will get you up and running within minutes.

Answer (score 4):

I have got good working experience with Joomla RSForm Pro. It has got options for

- validation
- user email/admin emails on submit
- file uploads
- and many more

Good tutorials too. Get started with http://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/view-knowledgebase/21-rsform-pro.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

1. Create View.
2. Create Model.
3. Create Table.
4. Create Controller ( if Needed ).
5. Create Form xml file.

Go here for more information:
http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Chronoforms extension - does more than you want.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Use an already built custom form extension
- Create your own custom form extension (or outsource it)

Now if you only want to modify the user registration form, then you can do some PHP customization to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Making forms in Joomla can be done in a couple of ways.

If you just wanted a contact us, you can just create a page with a menu item for the User contact form. This gives you a page with a Members address and contact form. So all you would need to do was add the user as the company of the websites home address and email. But the form is very basic, name, title, textarea for message.

Next up from that you could just make a Custom HTML module add add a form to it in plain HTML like +Sean said above this, you would need to code in PHP your own form process script. You would not get error in form data checking unless you also wrote it.

Next you might rather look on the Joomla Extension Directory JED for one of the good extensions for 3 and 2.5 Joomla [RSForms!Pro](http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html) is good, and can do all we have needed. This lets you add fields one by one and move your form around. Then can auto generate or custom the html of the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create your own forms with [Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Chronoforms are now a days a very popular solution for custom forms in joomla. Chornoforms support twitter bootstrap also. In simple 5 steps you can create a contact form with unlimited fields and also embed various function like DB save, Email, Thanks Message, Redirection on any page. There is events and events will have particular events.

Also possibility of extension of Normal joomla registeration. It will not extend the core registration but at the time of registration you can take various information from users.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Chrono Forms, they work really well and are easy to use.
[Download here](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms.html)

Here is a full tutorial on the new Chronoforms 5 to help you get started quickly and understand most of the features available.
[CLICK HERE](http://www.chronoengine.com/8-news/5202-chronoforms-v5-change-log.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin to insert external `php` form in content. It is easy and you don't need to make plugin etc. Please use [this](http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/DirectPHP-plugin.php#download).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use breezingforms: http://crosstec.de/en/extensions/joomla-forms-download.html

It's one of the best solutions for custom form creation in joomla.