# Difference between Module and Component in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, module, components

Can somebody please tell me what is the basic **difference** between the **module** and **component** in Joomla?

If possible, please tell with some examples, so that it is easily understood.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478220/joomla-components-modules-extensions-and-plugins

Comment: A really nice explanation is here.
https://www.collectiveray.com/joomla/joomla-tutorials/the-difference-between-modules-and-components.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Modules** are usually *small* pieces of functionality designed to _present information in your site). They can appear a number of times, on a number of pages in various positions.

On the other hand, a **component** is typically more complex, with extensive functionality and capabilities. A component can only be displayed in the main area of a page, and can usually only be displayed in a single page.

Read this article for more info: 
http://www.dart-creations.com/joomla/joomla-tutorials/the-difference-between-modules-and-components.html

Comment: article link not exist,   403 FORBIDDEN!

Comment: @ Abin M Devasia 
Explanation is here.
https://www.collectiveray.com/joomla/joomla-tutorials/the-difference-between-modules-and-components.html

Answer (score 7):

Taken from http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=344599#p1485432 by *David Hurley*.

> When I'm working with clients here is how I typically explain the differences.
>
> A **plugin** will **manipulate output already generated** by the system. It typically does not run as a stand-alone piece, but takes data from other sources (i.e. the content) and manipulates it before outputting to the user window. A plugin typically does not display directly to a user, but does its work behind the scenes.
>
> A **module** is typically considered to be an add-on to the site that **extends** the functionality of another part of the system. It usually has fewer options that are configurable by the end user and most of the time does not handle any storing of information into the database. A module usually occupies a secondary portion of the web page and is not considered the primary focus of a page.
>
> A **component** is the **most extensive add-on**. This typically adds completely new, or different, functionality to your site and extends the overall site possibilities. A component handles data manipulation as well as input and storage into the database. A component on most sites occupies the main area of the website layout and is the primary focus of the page.
>
> These are just generalizations and there are exceptions to every rule, but this should give you a good starting point.

Comment: copied from http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=344599#p1485432   and say thanks for davidhurley

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, any reason for distinguishing between components and modules is hidden in the technique of the Joomla framework. The fact that the main editorial content of a page is provided by a component, whereas subsidiary information (side frames, headers and footers, etc.) are provided by modules is not a real difference as far as the user is concerned. Page content is page content - full stop!

I think it is misleading to confuse users by stressing this difference. The way modules associate with menu items is probably technically different to the way the components do. Components are associated with a page on a one to one basis and they are run by triggering a menu item. Also modules do not always need to access the database whereas this is an integral part of a component. I expect these technical differences ultimately explain why Joomla has built the distinction in the the user interface. Perhaps avoiding this distinction would be the basis for Joomla version 4 - but I suspect this would mean starting from scratch with a totally new CMS :(

Answer (score 0):

A component always displays its results in the "mainbody" area of your template.

A module displays its results outside of the "mainbody" ... usually along the side, top, or bottom of the mainbody.

Comment: Yeah - Logically it's true .